# Convert Ruby Array to Hash of Key Value pairs, where the value is a constant

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I'm working with a Ruby API that takes a series of boolean switches, something along the lines of:

```
validate({ :can_foo => true, :can_bar => false, :can_baz => true, ... })
```

I'm writing a series of tests to verify that the API is behaving as it should, so I need to construct a lot of sets of switches. It seemed wasteful to continue to type :foo => true all the time, so I figured I'd write a little Ruby ditty to convert an array to this structure, e.g.

```
true_vals  = %w( these are my true  items )
false_vals = %w( these are my false items )

convert  = lambda{ |arr, truthiness| arr.inject({}){ |res, key| res.update(key=>truthiness) } }
falsify  = lambda{ |arr| convert.call(arr, false) }
truthify = lambda{ |arr| convert.call(arr, true)  }

validate( truthify.call(true_vals).merge( falsify.call(false_vals) ) )
```

Does that seem any better than simply typing out a long list of :sym => [true|false] pairs? Is there a better way to do this?

(I started with true_vals.inject({}){ |res, key| res.update(key=>true) } but that doesn't feel DRY enough; I'd have to copy-paste & s/true/false/ to do the false ones; and I'm doing it many many times so a lambda seems reasonable)

Thanks,

--
Matt

Comment: Are you just trying to automatically map each element of `true_vals` to `true` and `false_vals` to `false`?

Comment: yes. Not the generic "convert array to hash" that most people have...

Comment: I could do true_vals.inject({}){ |res, key| res.update(key=>true) } but that doesn't feel DRY enough; I'd have to copy-paste to do the false ones...

Comment: I don't understand the use of `lambda` here; how is that better than using methods and avoiding `.call`? Why not just make a method `booleanify(:true => [...], :false => [...])`?

Comment: no particular reason; I didn't want to pollute the namespace, but it doesn't matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cs = {  true =>   [:y, :yes], 
        false =>  [:n, :no] }
Hash[cs.map{ |k, vs| vs.map{ |v| [v, k] } }.flatten(1)]
#=> {:y=>true, :yes=>true, :no=>false, :n=>false}
```

Comment: +1, that's it, more Hash[] and less inject (unless until we get mash). Alternative: `Hash[cs.flat_map { |k, vs| vs.product([k]) }]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

```
switches={}
true_vals.each do |v|
    switches[v]=true
end
false_vals.each do |v|
    switches[v]=false
end
```

Comment: I don't hate it, but that means in every test I write, I have to do that block. It's not terrible, but it doesn't feel very DRY.

Comment: You could wrap it in a method. Again, its not very elegant, but it is much simpler to understand.